# To display a datepicker on click of checkbox

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I have a table
In the table first column displays a checkbox and second has a textbox.
Now i want onclick of a checkbox a datepicker should be enabled in the textbox of that specific row. and this should happen onclick of every checkbox in each row.

Here is wat i have tried:

//Inside View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Select((x, i) => new { Data = x, Index = i + 1 }))
    {
  <div class="cell"> <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" class="a"  onclick="checkbox1()" data-id="@item.ID" />
        </div>
 <div class="cell" id="edit2">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExhibEndDate)</div>
 <div class="cell" id="edit1">@Html.TextBox("Enddate", item.ExhibEndDate) </div>
```

//Javascript Code:

```
function checkbox1() {

    if ($('.a').is(':checked')) {
        $(this).document.getElementById('edit1').style.display = 'block';
        $(this).document.getElementById('edit2').style.display = 'none';           
    }
}
```

Here i tried hiding and displaying  tags but with this onclick of a checkbox in any row datepicker is enabled only in the textbox of first row.

Please help me i m really not able to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Select((x, i) => new { Data = x, Index = i + 1 }))
    {
  <div class="cell"> <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkbox(@item.Index)" />
        </div>
 <div class="cell" id="edit-@item.Index">@Html.TextBox("Enddate", item.ExhibEndDate) </div>
```

JS:

```
function checkbox(index){
     $(this).document.getElementById('edit-' + index).style.display = 'none';
}
```

Something like this. I hope you've got the point

Comment: hey act thr's one twist i get the datapicker wen i click inside the textbox but wen i choose date from it..it is updated only in the textbox  of first row...can u help hw shal i solve this

Comment: Can u giv some example lik i am not gettin hw shal i write the javascript and call it...

Comment: @Html.TextBox("Enddate", item.ExhibEndDate, new { id= Guid.NewGuid() })

Answer (score 1):

If you could add a container div for row like

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="cell"> <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" class="a"  onclick="checkbox1(this)" data-id="@item.ID" />
    </div>
    <div class="cell datePicker" id="edit2">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExhibEndDate)</div>
    <div class="cell dateTxt" id="edit1">@Html.TextBox("Enddate", item.ExhibEndDate) </div>
</div>
```

Then in jquery you can write

```
function checkbox1(chkBox)
{
    $('.datePicker').hide(); 
    $('.dateTxt').show();
    if ($(chkBox).is(':checked')) {
            $(chkBox).parents('.row').children('.datePicker').show();
            $(chkBox).parents('.row').children('.dateTxt').hide();
    }
}
```

This should work like charm. You won't be able to select elements if you have same ids. So add class names which you can use to query.